# Strange segmentation fault C++ in _vfprintf_r()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Someone please see my code at this [link](http://codepad.org/irBQYXPW) for input taken from 2.2 mb file.

This produces seg fault. By gdb, it shows seg fault in `_vfprintf_r()`. But when I comment line 41 and uncomment 38 (a null statement), there is no segmentation fault. line no 41 is just print statement.

The output is written into `result.txt` file.

Comment: What is the result if you printf("%d\n", v) ?

Comment: If you could provide the stack trace from gdb, that would be wonderful.  I copied it exactly as you have it on codepad, compiled it, grabbed your randomin2.txt and it worked perfectly (182350 line result.txt).

Comment: linked code compiles and runs for me, even with line 41 active.  no segfault.  gcc 4.2.4.

Comment: Oh is it because I am running on windows with cygwin

Comment: I should have included, gcc 4.1.2 for me.

Comment: Backtrace is just recursive visit() function calls.

Comment: Check to see if the calls to freopen return NULL or not.  I'm suspected that freopen("result.txt","w",stdout); is returning NULL and you're segfaulting trying to print to an invalid file descriptor.

Comment: No it prints some 40677 lines and then the error. I have checked results.txt file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stack overflow.  That's right, a Stack Overflow.  I was able to reproduce by doing ulimit -s 1024.  You need to not recurse so deeply, or you need to increase your stack size.

Comment: How to increase the stack size? But you did not get the error, u wrote in comment.

Comment: Its a simple dfs on around 200000 vertices. The file specifies the graph. I have to submit it to online judge. How to do it?

Comment: I didn't initially get the error.  I lowered the stack size available and was able to reproduce the error.  You can try ulimit -s <value> (my system defaults to 8192) to try and solve the issue, but I'm not sure if cygwin supports setting the stack size.  A stack size of 2048 did not generate the error.

Comment: So if I run on linux system, then I wont get error?

Comment: Thank you Matt and all others for looking at this problem. I will try on linux and then update.

Comment: "That's right, a Stack Overflow." -- I tried searching to find what was so funny about that, but I got a Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ya it runs on linux perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt answered, you're running out of stack.
Add
/STACK:amount to reserve in bytes,amount to initially commit in bytes
to your link.exe command line.

Make sure both numbers are multiples of 4096, which is the default page size on windows IIRC.